# Modelling data in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of users for my database, and a fixed set of 30-35 properties which each user may have. These properties may change over time, so I have created nodes for each of these properties and one node for each user .

For updating the properties, I connect or delete the relationship for that user with the corresponding properties, I have assigned each user and property a unique id.

I would like to answer queries like count of user which have ( property1 and property2 and property3 ), count of users with (property1 or property2 ), etc

How can I answer query of first type ?  for two properties I use :

```
match (p1:property)<--(n:user)-->(p2:property) p1.id=1 and p2.id=2  return count(distinct(n))
```

How can I answer for multiple properties joined with 'and' clause, It's easy for 'or' clause using :

```
 match (n:user)-->(p:property) where p.id in [1,2] return count(distinct(n))
```

How can I answer queries with combination of 'and' and 'or' clauses like: 
users with ( (property1 and property2) or (property1 and property2) )

Also can indices help in the above case as I am mostly interested in getting count of users ?

Comment: Hello! Why are you modelling properties as nodes?

Comment: Because these properties may changing frequently with time,                                    Also user relates booleanly with these fixed properties, i.e. user may/maynot have some of these properties.                                                 And if new fixed property needs to be added in future, I can simply create a node and add edges as required .

Comment: So i thought it would be a good idea to keep these properties as nodes .

Comment: Why not simply check by the existence of relationship? Like this: `MATCH (u:user)
WHERE
    (u)-->(:property {id : 1})
AND 
    (u)-->(:property {id : 2})`

Comment: The problem is that you needs to specify all the properties in the query?

Comment: Yeah this is working, but taking too much time `MATCH (u:user)-->(p:property{id:1}) return count(distinct(u))` runs in around 4.5 seconds while `MATCH (u:user) where (u)-->(p:property{id:1})` takes around 50 seconds !!

Comment: Are you using an index?

Comment: But bases on your reply I found an option `MATCH (u:user)-->(p1:property{id:1}),(u:user)-->(p2:property{id:2}) return count(distinct(u))` which is working and also running fast. Thanks !

Comment: No, not using any index at present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases you can check by the path existence between a node and properties, like this:

1 - Count of user which have `property1` and `property2` and `property3`:

```
MATCH (u:user)
WHERE
    (u)-->(:property {id : 1})
AND
    (u)-->(:property {id : 2})
AND
    (u)-->(:property {id : 3})
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(u))
```

Alternatively:

```
MATCH (u:user),
(u)-->(:property {id : 1}),
(u)-->(:property {id : 2}),
(u)-->(:property {id : 3})
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(u))
```

2 - Count of user which have `property1` and `property2` **OR** `property3`:

```
MATCH (u:user)
WHERE
    (u)-->(:property {id : 1})
AND
    (u)-->(:property {id : 2})
OR
    (u)-->(:property {id : 3})
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(u))
```

To improve performance try adding an index in the `id` property of your :property nodes. This way:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :property(id)
```

Comment: not much improvement on creating index though, let me see if i can modify the data model somehow to make queries faster using index .

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not convinced that you want every property to be a node. New properties can be **SET**, obsolete ones can be **REMOVE**d. And the existence of a property can be checked with **EXISTS**.

There surely can be a reason to turn a property into a node, but the above is not it (imo).

Hope this helps,
Tom